# How to quickly build Ionic2 app for android debugging purpose

Tags: ionic2

I am currently developing Ionic2 app. I want to know if there is any way to quickly build `apk` for testing on Android device. Because it takes time to run `ionic run android`

Comment: how slow is your build?

Comment: `ionic emulate android` works just fine if Android environment is set up. Could you please be more specific about the procedure you are following and how much time it is taking now?

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be done as it would load all angular files and convert it to APK, well it is an under developing technologies so the developer will gradually improve it.